# How to configure Spring Cloud LoadBalancer with SpringCloudOpenFeign

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, java-17, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

Changing a work project's version to java 17 resulted in the need to increase the spring-cloud-starter-openfeign to 3.0.6 (part of the 2020.0.0 Spring Cloud release train).
Since Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon has been deprecated and is not included in the 2020.0.0 release train, I have to make some changes in my project and switch to using Spring Cloud LoadBalancer.

After reading some articles I got the following understanding: Feign was using Ribbon as a LoadBalancer. Ribbon was configured in a properties file with different lists of hosts for all the applications clients.

My questions are:

1. How am I supposed to use  Spring Cloud LoadBalancer since I did not manage to find any comprehensible examples for me?
2. Since I am using SpringCloudOpenFeign 3.0.6, which would be the suitable spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer version? I have tried using 3.0.5( but I get a  **Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @RequestMapping annotation not allowed on @FeignClient interfaces**) and also 3.1.0 (**and I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClientsProperties**); did not find any related info for neither of the errors on google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find comprehensive documentation of Spring Cloud LoadBalancer, with all the details on how to set it up [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-loadbalancer). You can use it with Service Registry or, if you want to pass the list of hosts manually in properties, you can use [`SimpleDiscoveryClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#simplediscoveryclient)  You can also find a sample that uses Spring Cloud OpenFeign with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/feign-eureka) - the `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` dependency is not in the pom, but gets included transitively via `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`. For more information about switching from Spring Cloud Netflix - based stack to the currently supported Spring Cloud stack, you can also watch this [presentation recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mINNQ3zpRrE).

Spring Cloud OpenFeign `3.0.5` works with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer `3.0.4`, however, manually setting library versions for Spring Cloud is discouraged in general. You should use dependency management instead. You can find the setup at [Spring Cloud projects landing page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud). Also, the easiest way to generate a correct build file for Spring Cloud Projects is to use [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/).

Comment: I have removed the ribbon dependencies and  added the Spring Cloud LoadBalancer, configured SimpleDiscoveryClient properties (cloud:discovery:client:simple:instances:my-service[0]:uri: localhost:8070). At startup when I use the breakpoint in SimpleDiscoveryClient  I can see that it manages to get it's instances using getInstances() but when it makes a call to one of the services I receive : "Method threw 'feign.RetryableException' exception." with message : "null executing GET http://my-service/app/v1/data". Did I miss to add anyhthing in my configurations ?

Comment: Finally managed to fix the problem. When configuring the hosts for Ribbon in the properties file they worked as host:7080 but it seems that for the cloud load balancer it does not work without specifying the protocol (PASS THE HOST  as https ://host:7080). Thank you for the support Olga!

Comment: @skorpyo You can set scheme, like so: `spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.my-service[0].uri=https://localhost:8880`